# How to use data.map function in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,Right now i am trying to fetch data using "map" function,How can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
export default function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const callData = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products').then(data => data.json())
      console.log(data);
      setData(data)
    }
    callData()
  }, [])

  return (
   //want to use map function here
    );

}
```

Comment: Show some sample data so we can see the structure, and what does the markup you want look like?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @MrCode I just want to fetch data ( id, title) in webpage , thats it

Answer (score 0):

Well dummyjson will return you an object wich will contain { products, total, skip, limit } in your return you can write

```
{data.products.map((product) => <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>)}
```

paragraph in map can be your ArticleItem or everything you want.

Comment: @Viktoi Viktor Dimitrov i am getting following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

Comment: then try {data && data.products.map((product) => <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>)} , this is because on first render data is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

so you could do this, check if the state has any data in it then `map` through, if not show some other message.
Not sure how your data state is structured, but this should help

```
return(
<div>
{
 data.length ? data.map(({id: number, title: string}) => <p key={id}>{title}</p>) : do something if data is empty
}
</div>)
```

Comment: i am getting following error : " Binding element 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @Jennie you need to add the type. not sure which types are coming from your response, the id could be a number or string just use the appropriate type